# Better Rebol Syntax than head remove back tail (remove mold b)?

Tags: rebol

I want to transform a block to strings like this

```
>> b: [field "field1" tab field "field2"]
== [field "field1" tab field "field2"]
>> head remove back tail (remove mold b)
== {field "field1" tab field "field2"}
>>
```

Is there a better syntax than this ?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**mold/only** should do the trick:

```
b: [field "field1" tab field "field2"]
mold/only b
== {field "field1" tab field "field2"}
```

Comment: Oh yeah that's luch better :)